# Corrosion on kitchen faucet

Tags: kitchen-sink, corrosion

I have some corrosion on a brushed nickel kitchen faucet. It's mostly where it rotates and where the filter connects, but it's a bit all over. I don't knowingly use corrosive cleaners on it or hang the wash cloth on it. My only guess is galvanic corrosion, but I'm surprised to see it on a mass-produced faucet.

Has anyone seen this before? What causes it? How can I prevent it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mass produced is your first clue.

Comment: What should I buy, then? If it's not Delta, Moen, Pfister, or Kohler, where should I be looking?

Comment: I am not sure.  I have stuff from the 70s and 90s still working and looking good.  I do worry about having to buy recent stuff if something breaks/need replacing.  The quality/workmanship seems to have gone down.  Your local conditions might be different and nickel plating is not the not best finish.

Comment: Try to polish it off to see what is happening

Comment: It almost looks like deposits from water. Try lemon juice on it.

Comment: @Stewart Miller,  try Hansgrohe  or Grohe. (2 different companies)  I have used both.  Excellent quality with a still reasonable price.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the spout was not plated as well as the handles and trim.

Sorry to say it has reached the end of its' esthetic life.

If you saved any paperwork of know the manufacturer you may be able to file a warranty claim.